# Embedding only selected characters from fonts with ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, fonts

I would like to embed just a subset of characters from a font (for example only a certain number of Chinese characters instead of the whole character set).

The traditional way I've known how to do this is using the "Include these characters" input box method outlined below:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000277.html

Is there a way to do the equivalent using only ActionScript? (and without using Flex)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with FLEX: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_07.html

Answer (score 1):

Fonts can be embeded using just actionscript with the embed metatag. For example:

```
[Embed(source = 'myfont.ttf', fontFamily = "MyFont", unicodeRange = 'U+0041-U+005A,U+0061-U+007A')]
var FontClass :  Class;
```

See [here](http://www.allflashwebsite.com/article/embedding-fonts-in-flash-cs3-the-good-way) for more information.